# Using null key in html form array

Tags: php, html, forms, post

In an html form, it is possible to send data as an array.

```
<!-- This is an associative array -->
<input name="table[key1]">
<input name="table[key2]">

<!-- This is an index-based array -->
<input name="table[]">
<input name="table[]">
```

Is it possible to store a value into an associative array, using an empty string as a key?
So that php could access the data with `$_POST["table"][null]`

Answer (score -1):

`null` is not an empty string, that would be a `''` or a `""`.
However, PHP will convert it to an empty string and use that as a key (Look under Example 1 at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

So these are equivalent:

```
$a = array('' => 'hello');
$b = array(null => 'hello');
```

From your example, the data would be in `$_POST["table"][""]`

Comment: I'm aware that null casts to an empty string when used as an array key, I was just using that as grammatical sugar. The question now is how do I insert an empty-string key into the array from the _html_ side of code ?

Comment: I see @Estecka, I misunderstood the question. Did you try `<input name="table['']">` or are you only looking for a way to use `null`?

Comment: I did, `table['']` generates the string `"''"`, not en empty string.